# How to deploy my react app on GitHub pages in such a way that my deployment will be exactly like "someName.github.io"

Tags: reactjs, git, github, deployment, github-pages

I have a react app and I have installed `gh-pages` in it but  I don't know how can I specifically deploy the app to the url `Name.github.io` example `abdullahch.github.io`. What changes should I do in my `package.json` and `package-lock.json`.